# React requiring a peer React-Dom

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new in React and front end dev.

I am following a tutorial from udemy that require to install react-simple-sidenav module in order to get a NavBar.

However when I try to install it no way to make it work. I get the following error message after running the command npm install react-simple-sidenav

And the navBar doest not work event if it is copy past from the tuto

npm WARN react-simple-sidenav@0.1.6 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer depe
ndencies yourself.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install react-dom from NPM library, in your command line type the following:

```
npm i -s react-dom
```